# Automated monthly report Python-Jira

Tags: python, python-requests, python-datetime, python-jira

A small request. I'm a junior in Python and Jira but I want to learn :)
I have a code from a colleague that left the company for automated report of number of incidents in last 12 months! 
What I want to have is number of incidents automated monthly report of 2020. Below you can find the code. **What I have to change? THX!**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import requests
from datetime import date
import datetime
import calendar
from utils import jira_utils, table_utils


# Method section

DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_MONTHS= 12

def create_data_table(month):
    header_row = table_utils.create_start_of_data_table_monthly_report(DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_MONTHS)
    data_rows=create_data_row('P1', month)
    data_rows+=create_data_row('P2', month)
    data_rows+=create_data_row('P3', month)

    #data_rows+=create_data_row('P1, P2, P3', month)
    end_of_table = table_utils.end_table()
    return header_row + data_rows + end_of_table

def create_data_row(priority, month):
    data_row='<tr><th>' + priority + '</th>'
    for i in range (-1*DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_MONTHS, 0, 1):
        if month:
            time_frame=table_utils.define_time_range_for_monthly_report(i)
        else:
            time_frame=table_utils.define_time_range_for_weekly_report(i)
        row_value = calculate_total_from_jira(priority, time_frame)
        data_cell='<td><p>'+str(row_value)+'</p></td>'
        data_row+=data_cell
    data_row+='</tr>'
    return data_row

def calculate_total_from_jira(priority, time_frame):
    jql_search = calculate_jira_query(time_frame, priority)
    # Authenticate on Jira REST API and fetch results for reporting period
    resp=jira_utils.query_jsd(jql_search)
    return resp['total']

def calculate_jira_query(time_frame, priority):
    start_day = time_frame['repstart']
    end_day = time_frame['repend']
    #print(start_day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00'))
    #print(end_day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:59'))
    jira_query='{"jql": "project = SM AND issuetype=Incident AND createdDate >= '+ start_day+' AND createdDate <= \\\"'+ end_day +'\\\" AND priority IN ('+priority+') AND resolution NOT IN (Duplicate, Rejected) ORDER BY issuekey","startAt":0, "maxResults":1000, "fields":["total"]}'
    #print(jira_query)
    return jira_query

def number_of_incidents(month):
    data_table = create_data_table(month)
    return data_table
```

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question. What actual problem do you have with the code? What is the current outcome? What is your expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

ok, when I put this: 
DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_MONTHS= int(datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%m"))-1
I receive right data for 2020. Problem will be with decmber of 2020. I will get 'No data' on my report.

How to add range [1,13] to this part:
for i in range (-1*DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_MONTHS, 0, 1):